# PHP Fatal Error in compiled.php after composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5.1 in my production server. After update my composer, queue listener command starts throwing error as

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable in /var/www/<site-folder>/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 6109
```

I couldn't find out the problem. My site is working fine, and other artisan commands are working fine. But I can't run my queue. Please suggest me some sollution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run Run

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

and make you sure you restart your queue.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above. Still no luck :(

Comment: And if you manually remove this `bootstrap/compiled.php` file does the error disappear?

Comment: I guess it worked. I removed the compiled.php and it is working fine. Can you tell me why the removal of compiled.php worked, why it didn't affect the site and other commands? Most importantly what is the use of that file? Please update these questions in your answer, it will be useful.

Comment: This file is for performance reasons. Running `php artisan clear-compiled` should remove this file, but running again `php artisan optimize` should create it again with fresh content and in theory everything should be fine. But it's possible you have some bug in your code or there is a bug in this version of Laravel